# Is the "community help wiki" the same as "community wiki" on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, faq, community-wiki

I've heard of **community wiki** posts on Ask Ubuntu, but there seems to be something else called **the community wiki**, the **community help wiki**, or **Ubuntu community wiki**.

This is confusing. What's the difference?

<sub>This is related to [Why do some questions have "community wiki" over the user's name?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/67/why-do-some-questions-have-community-wiki-over-the-users-name). (Please read that!) But this is different.

This question is *specifically* to address some confusion I've seen over the past few weeks about CW posts and Ubuntu docs.</sub>

Comment: Also related (but *not* a duplicate): [Where are the community wikis?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/154/where-are-the-community-wikis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Community wiki" posts on Ask Ubuntu are **completely unrelated** to the coincidentally named Ubuntu community help wiki. This is sometimes a source of confusion.

### "Community Wiki" Posts Here

**Community wiki** posts on [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) sites (including Ask Ubuntu) are a special kind of post where:

- They belong more to the whole community, than to any individual author.
- More easily edited: Only 100 reputation is required to edit it without approval.
- Authors don't gain or lose any reputation (since they don't really "own" the post in the usual way).

For more information, see:

- **[What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)**
- [Create community-wiki posts (privilege)](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/community-wiki)
- [Edit community wiki (privilege)](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki)

### How to Tell If a Post Is Community Wiki

The bottom of a normal (non-CW) post looks like:

[image: bottom of a non-CW post showing one author]

Or if the non-CW post was last edited by someone other than its original author, it looks like this:

[image: bottom of a non-CW post showing two authors]

**This appears under a community wiki (CW) post, instead:**

[image: bottom of a CW post]

The CW post de-emphasizes its authors (as it is more owned by the whole community, see above), and says ***community wiki***.

### The Ubuntu Community Help/Documentation Wiki

There are two wikis on [Ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/):

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ — Organizes community involvement/contributions to Ubuntu.
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community — End-user documentation written by volunteers.

The latter is often called:

- [**Ubuntu**] **community documentation wiki**
- [**Ubuntu**] **community help wiki**
- [**Ubuntu**] **community wiki**
- [**Ubuntu**] **community documentation**
- [**Ubuntu**] **help wiki**
- [**Ubuntu**] **community docs**
- **UserDocumentation** *(rarely used in prose — this is its main page's wikified title)*

(Where *[Ubuntu]* is sometimes included and other times omitted.)

While none of those names for it are *wrong*, I recommend avoiding calling it anything with "community wiki" in its name (without any intermediate words between them).

### Ask Ubuntu and the Help Wiki: Similarities and Differences

While *CW posts* on Ask Ubuntu are unrelated to the *Ubuntu community help wiki*, the *commmunity help wiki* does overlap Ask Ubuntu as a whole, in purpose.

Ask Ubuntu is [a wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki)--not just the *community wiki* posts, but everything.

- It's a somewhat atypical wiki, as it is also a question-and-answer site.
- But [its primary purpose is to provide reusable documentation about Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/about), which is similar to the help wiki's purpose.

[The community help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community) also exists to provide reusable documentation about Ubuntu. However, it is more of a classic wiki. It consists of traditional-style articles on topics within Ubuntu, rather than questions and answers.

- The community help wiki is a frequently used source, and a number of pages are referred to regularly as canonical (i.e., standard, widely accepted) resources on their topics. These include [UserDocumentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community), [Repositories/Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu), [HowToMD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM), [Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba), [DataRecovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery), [Lubuntu/Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation), and [PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure).

  There are some equally venerable user documentation pages that, for historical reasons or because they are particularly useful for volunteers, are part of the [wiki.ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/) wiki instead, like [WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) and [Apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport).
- However, currently a number of pages on the help wiki are outdated (though often still useful). For example, [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) is still useful but was never truly updated to cover releases past 9.10. In contrast, **[How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)** (here on Ask Ubuntu) is more up-to-date and provides more varied and accessible advice.

### Sharing Content

[User-contributed content on Ask Ubuntu is published](http://stackexchange.com/legal) under [the CC-BY-SA 3.0 license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) ([full legal code](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode)).

This is true of user-contributed content on other Stack Exchange sites too.

Both [wiki.ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/) and the [Ubuntu community documentation wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community) (i.e., the help wiki) are **[licensed CC-BY-SA 3.0 as well](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/License)**.

This means that ***with proper attribution***, content from any of these sources may be reused in the others. See [the Ubuntu wikis' attribution requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/License), as well as [those for Stack Exchange sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

- CC-BY-SA 3.0 gives substantial (albeit limited) power to authors to dictate how their content should be cited when republished or integrated into another work, and it is important to abide by the license terms.
- It's a good idea to take a look at [the actual license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode), especially if you're unsure of anything, and to err on the side of making it perfectly clear what sources you've used, who wrote them, and where they can be found.
- *By the way, I'm not a laywer, and nothing in this post is legal advice!*

A ([mostly](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#What_are_Repositories.3F)) [free (as in freedom)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_content) operating system deserves free documentation, and Ubuntu has it. [The official, Canonical Ltd. endorsed documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/) is also (unless indicated otherwise) [licensed CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://help.ubuntu.com/legal.html).

However, **not all Ubuntu resources are necessarily licensed so as to allow content to be taken from or integrated into Ask Ubuntu questions and answers.**

For example, [the "Ubuntu Guide"](http://ubuntuguide.org/) is offered under a different Creative Commons license ([CC-NC-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)), which does not allow commerical redistribution. Since CC-BY-SA 3.0 **does** allow this, without permission from the author(s), CC-BY-SA content may not relicensed CC-NC-SA, nor CC-NC-SA content relicensed CC-BY-SA.