# What does "non-community wiki" mean?

Tags: support, badges

I am a bit confused about the **Tag badges**.
For ex, a **Bronze tag badge** for 10.04 says

> Earned at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki answers in the 10.04 tag

I know what *community* is, I know what *wiki* Q&A are.But what is non-community wiki?

Does it mean answers(or questions) that are wiki's but made wiki by someone other than community?

Comment: Related: [Is the “community help wiki” the same as “community wiki” on Ask Ubuntu?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5976/is-the-community-help-wiki-the-same-as-community-wiki-on-ask-ubuntu)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's intended to be read as

> non-**(**community wiki**)**

rather than:

> **(**non-community**)** wiki

That is, "non-community wiki" (in this context) means posts that aren't community wiki, rather than posts that are wiki in some way other than being community wiki.

You might want to submit a bug post on Meta.SO requesting the wording be changed, if you believe it's confusing. I wouldn't recommend changing "non-community wiki" to "non community wiki" or "non community-wiki," but I would suggest a rewording to something like this:

> Earned at least 100 total score for at least 20 answers (except community wiki) in the **(tag name)** tag

Or this:

> Earned at least 100 total score for at least 20 answers (that are not community wiki) in the **(tag name)** tag

Or:

> Earned at least 100 total score for at least 20 answers (other than community wiki) in the **(tag name)** tag

When similar opportunities for confusion arise on meta, I usually use the less formal "CW" as an abbreviation for community wiki. While "non-community wiki" is confusing because intuitively dashes have higher precedence than spaces, "non-CW" remains unambiguous.

That might also be suggested as an alternative wording for the badge description. But "CW" might confuse people who don't know it stands for "community wiki."

Answer (score 3):

I think that to understand non-community wiki, you have to understand what is a community wiki:

- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/213575)

Non-community wiki is the opposite of a community wiki.